# How to enumerate through IDictionary

Tags: c#

How can I enumerate through an IDictionary? Please refer to the code below.

```
 public IDictionary<string, string> SelectDataSource
 {
    set
    {
        // This line does not work because it returns a generic enumerator,
        // but mine is of type string,string
        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = value.GetEnumerator();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manual enumeration is very rare (compared to `foreach`, for example) - the first thing I'd suggest is: check you really need that.  However, since a dictionary enumerates as key-value-pair:

```
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string,string>> enumerator = value.GetEnumerator();
```

should work. Or if it is *only* a method variable (not a field), then:

```
var enumerator = value.GetEnumerator();
```

or better (since if it isn't a field it probably needs local disposal):

```
using(var enumerator = value.GetEnumerator())
{ ... }
```

or best ("KISS"):

```
foreach(var pair in value)
{ ... }
```

However, you should also always *dispose* any existing value when replaced. Also, a set-only property is exceptionally rare. You *really* might want to check there isn't a simpler API here... for example, a method taking the dictionary as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(var keyValuePair in value)
{
     //Do something with keyValuePair.Key
     //Do something with keyValuePair.Value
}
```

OR

```
IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string,string>> enumerator = dictionary.GetEnumerator();

using (enumerator)
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        //Do something with enumerator.Current.Key
        //Do something with enumerator.Current.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: An `IDictionary<string, string>` doesn't return `Dictionary<string, string>.Enumerator` ;p Or rather, it *might*, if the concrete implementation happens to be the concrete `Dictionary<,>` - but it isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want enumerate it simply use `foreach(var item in myDic) ...` for sample implementation see [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

## Smooth solution

```cs
using System.Collections;

IDictionary dictionary = ...;

foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in dictionary) {
    object key = kvp.Key;
    object value = kvp.Value;
}
```